# HTML 5 / Canvas Polygon Draw Tool?

Tags: javascript, canvas

For a upcomming project we're doing some research on possibilities for drawing shapes using HTML. The drawing libary used in Google Maps (http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.nl/2011/11/make-your-map-interactive-with-shape.html) would be very nice to use. Already found something similar on Mapbox (https://www.mapbox.com/guides/adding-features-and-data/) but they are all map-based and we need just an empty sheet to draw some shapes on...

Anyone knows a standalone tool like examples above?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw strokes over an image that's been drawn to the canvas.

It's so simple you don't even need an add-on library. Just use native Path commands!

- Listen for user's mouseclicks and create an array of their click-points

  ```
  // some test points
  // In production, these would be gathered through user mouseclicks
  var points=[]
  points.push({x:100,y:300});
  points.push({x:150,y:250});
  points.push({x:235,y:225});
  points.push({x:190,y:300});
  points.push({x:80,y:340});
  ```
- This draws a polyline:

  ```
  function drawPolyline(points){
      for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
          for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
              ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
          }
          ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
          ctx.lineWidth=5;
          ctx.stroke();    
      }
  }
  ```
- This draws a circle to highlight the waypoints:

  ```
  function drawWaypoints(points){
      for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(points[i].x,points[i].y,4,0,Math.PI*2);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.strokeStyle='black';
          ctx.lineWidth=1;
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.fillStyle='white';
          ctx.fill();
      }
  }
  ```

**Example code and a Demo:**

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// some test points
// In production, these would be gathered through user mouseclicks
var points=[]
points.push({x:100,y:300});
points.push({x:150,y:250});
points.push({x:235,y:225});
points.push({x:190,y:300});
points.push({x:80,y:340});

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/googlemap1.png";
function start(){
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  drawPolyline(points);
  drawWaypoints(points);
}

function drawPolyline(points){
  for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
    for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
      ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
    ctx.lineWidth=5;
    ctx.stroke();    
  }
}

function drawWaypoints(points){
  for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(points[i].x,points[i].y,4,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='black';
    ctx.lineWidth=1;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```